# Importing Functions into Current Namespace

Tags: r

Let's say I have an R source file comprised of some functions, doesn't matter what they are, e.g.,

```
fnx = function(x){(x - mean(x))/sd(x)}
```

I would like to be able to access them in my current R session (without typing them in obviously). It would be nice if library("/path/to/file/my_fn_lib1.r") worked, as "import" works in Python, but it doesn't. One obvious solution is to create an R Package, but i want to avoid that overhead just to import a few functions.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use the `source()` command.  In your case:

```
source("/path/to/file/my_fn_lib1.r")
```

Incidentally, creating a package is fairly easy with the `package.skeleton()` function (if you're planning to reuse this frequently).

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for, though in fact, the package.skeleton(), which i wasn't aware of prior to your Answer, was far easier than i thought and I actually used that in the end. Thanks!

Comment: It probably should be pointed out that the `devtools` package makes creating R packages ridiculously easy.

Comment: As of 2020, which is the suggested tool to create packages in R: devtool, skeleton or something else?